# Alert Dialog error

Tags: android

I'm trying to watch an AlertDialog with two options: Cámara and Galería. But when I run the app it closes with the message "Unfortunately, MapaLugares has closed".

The logcat message is:

```
08-15 20:37:02.960: E/AndroidRuntime(5377): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-15 20:37:02.960: E/AndroidRuntime(5377):  
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is   
not for an application
08-15 20:37:02.960: E/AndroidRuntime(5377):         at  
android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:521)
08-15 20:37:02.960: E/AndroidRuntime(5377):     at 
android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:301)
08-15 20:37:02.960: E/AndroidRuntime(5377):     at 
android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
08-15 20:37:02.960: E/AndroidRuntime(5377):     at 
android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
08-15 20:37:02.960: E/AndroidRuntime(5377):     at  
android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:289)
08-15 20:37:02.960: E/AndroidRuntime(5377):     at 
com.app.mapa.Insertarlugar$1.onClick(Insertarlugar.java:62)
08-15 20:37:02.960: E/AndroidRuntime(5377):     at  
android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3521)
08-15 20:37:02.960: E/AndroidRuntime(5377):     at 
android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14185)
08-15 20:37:02.960: E/AndroidRuntime(5377):     at 
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
08-15 20:37:02.960: E/AndroidRuntime(5377):     at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-15 20:37:02.960: E/AndroidRuntime(5377):     at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-15 20:37:02.960: E/AndroidRuntime(5377):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4464)
08-15 20:37:02.960: E/AndroidRuntime(5377):     at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-15 20:37:02.960: E/AndroidRuntime(5377):     at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-15 20:37:02.960: E/AndroidRuntime(5377):     at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:822)
08-15 20:37:02.960: E/AndroidRuntime(5377):     at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:589)
08-15 20:37:02.960: E/AndroidRuntime(5377):     at 
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-15 20:37:05.210: I/ActivityThread(5573): Pub com.app.mapa.MCProvider:   
com.app.mapa.MCProvider
08-15 20:37:05.570: D/memalloc(5573): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x5127b000 
size:2826240 offset:1290240 fd:51
08-15 20:37:05.620: E/Adreno200-ES20(5573): <qgl2DrvAPI_glUseProgram:1318>: **** 5573: 
glUseProgram(3)
08-15 20:37:05.650: E/Adreno200-ES20(5573): <qgl2DrvAPI_glUseProgram:1318>: **** 5573: 
glUseProgram(6)
08-15 20:37:05.670: D/memalloc(5573): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x516f7000 
size:4362240 offset:2826240 fd:58
```

The code:

```
public class Insertarlugar extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_insertarlugar);

    ImageButton imgbutton;

    imgbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgButton);
    EditText titlugar; 
    EditText desclugar;
            titlugar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_titulo_lugar);
    String tlugar = titlugar.getText().toString();

    desclugar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_descripcion_lugar);
    String dlugar = desclugar.getText().toString();

    imgbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                       final String[] items = {"Cámara", "Galería"};

             AlertDialog.Builder builder = new 
                     AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
             builder.setTitle("Foto");
             builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

                     Toast.makeText(Insertarlugar.this, "Click\n" + item, 
                             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
             });
             AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
             alert.show();

         } 
});
}
```

What's wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Try using `Insertarlugar.this` instead of `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: You are passing the wrong context at the Dialog. You should use the current context and not the applicationContext!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
```

to

```
AlertDialog.Builder(Insertarlugar.this);
```

A `Dialog` is created on the `Activity` so you want to use its `Context` to create it and not the application's `Context`. This is true for most `UI` objects, as far as I understand `Context`. Sometimes this may work for some objects such as a `Toast` but, in my opinion, it is always better to try and use the correct `Context` which here is the `Activity`'s.

And see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context/7298955#7298955) about when to use which `Context`

Comment: -1 because this is a hard typed solution, you shouldn't get context like this when it's freely available through the View's methods ... bad practice.  If you rename your activity, cut/paste code into another activity this sort of thing will result in more errors

Comment: @Merlin That's hardly a reason for a downvote, IMHO, it is still a correct answer and widely used. And this is easily changed if you do rename your `Activity` or copy/paste the code. Downvotes should be used for incorrect or offensive answers...not because its not the way you would do it

Comment: Offensive answers should be dealt with using moderator flags.  Downvotes are for asnwers which are not useful (hover over the down arrow and you'll see what I mean).  Using the `this` pointer in this manner may be common but bad practice is never useful. If any of my dev's are caught using it they are sent to the corner of the room to think about what they did wrong

Comment: I also tried Alert.Dialog.Builder(getContext()); but error wasn't fixed. Now with our answers it works fine. Thank you very much. I'll see the answer about when to use right Context because it's not clear for me.

Comment: You needed to use `arg0.getContext()` (which `arg0` should have been changed to something like `v` or `view`), if you are referring to the other answer, to get the `Context` associated with the `View` which will do the same thing here. But Merlin's answer is a more portable answer and probably better practice. But either is "correct".

Comment: Reading that answer about `Context` and maybe look around at some others will definitely help. It can take awhile to get a full understanding of it.

Answer (score 1):

As the others have mentioned in the comments, your context is wrong.  Thankfully this is easily fixed by using the [View.getContext()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext%28%29) method.

```
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                   final String[] items = {"Cámara", "Galería"};

         AlertDialog.Builder builder = new 
                 AlertDialog.Builder(arg0.getContext());
         builder.setTitle("Foto");
         builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

                 Toast.makeText(Insertarlugar.this, "Click\n" + item, 
                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
         });
         AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
         alert.show();

     }
```